# 12 V LED used with 12 V, 6A power supply

Tags: led, voltage, current

There is some unknown factor here. I need to use an LED to light an area of a device. The device has a 12V, 6A power supply. I was expecting to have to reduce the current from 6A in order to use the 12V LED but the LED is working as -is, connected directly to the 12V, 6A supply. How can this be? I expected the LED to get hot or to burn out. It isn't even getting warm. I'd like to know why.

Answer (score 6):

Power supplies don't push current; loads pull. 6A is the **maximum** current that the supply can provide, but it's perfectly happy to supply less. If you have a load that's rated for 12 volts and you attach it to that supply (or any other 12 volt source) it will draw the current that it needs.

Comment: It's this kind of answer with explanation that newbies like myself really appreciate, to drive home the basics before bad thoughts happen to us =)

Answer (score 3):

The LED already contains the appropriate resistor to reduce the current to an acceptable level given a 12V power supply.

Comment: Logical, there are no details on the LEDs. Should they not get warm due to the resistor?

Comment: 12V times 20mA is 240mW. That is true regardless of the resistor.

Answer (score 2):

You had to connect a 12V LED directly to 12V! There is a build in resistor, so the current will be fine.